# Best approach for Cartesian product or 2 large text files

Tags: c#, .net, windows, filestream, large-files

I have problem where I want to merge 2 large text files together and generate new file with cartesian product of 2 input files.
I do know how code would look but not sure in which language to build such a utility. I have windows server and I'm familiar with C#, Shell script.

Note : File1 can be around 20 MB and File2 can contain around 6000 records. So what I want to achieve is Copy 20MB data 6000 times in new file.

Below are smaller examples of how my files would look like

File1

```
Head-A-AA-AAA
Child-A1-AA1-AAA1
Child-A2-AA2-AAA2
Child-A3-AA3-AAA3
Head-B-BB-BBB
Child-B1-BB1-BBB1
Child-B2-BB2-BBB2
Child-B3-BB3-BBB3
```

File2

```
Store1
Store2
Store3
```

Expected output file

```
Store1
Head-A-AA-AAA
Child-A1-AA1-AAA1
Child-A2-AA2-AAA2
Child-A3-AA3-AAA3
Head-B-BB-BBB
Child-B1-BB1-BBB1
Child-B2-BB2-BBB2
Child-B3-BB3-BBB3
Store2
Head-A-AA-AAA
Child-A1-AA1-AAA1
Child-A2-AA2-AAA2
Child-A3-AA3-AAA3
Head-B-BB-BBB
Child-B1-BB1-BBB1
Child-B2-BB2-BBB2
Child-B3-BB3-BBB3
Store3
Head-A-AA-AAA
Child-A1-AA1-AAA1
Child-A2-AA2-AAA2
Child-A3-AA3-AAA3
Head-B-BB-BBB
Child-B1-BB1-BBB1
Child-B2-BB2-BBB2
Child-B3-BB3-BBB3
```

Looking for suggestion if C# code with windows service will serve purpose or I need to use any other tool/utility/scripting?

**EDIT : Created below c# code. But it's taking hours to generate 150 GB output file. I'm looking for faster way. I'm taking content from file 1 and copying it for each record in second file**

```
FileInfo[] fi;
            List<FileInfo> TodaysFiles = new List<FileInfo>();
            string PublishId;
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\InputPath");

            fi = di.GetFiles().Where(file => file.FullName.Contains("TRANSMIT_MASS")).ToArray();

            foreach (FileInfo f in fi)
            {
                string[] tokens = f.Name.Split('_');
                if(tokens[2] == DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToString("MMddyyyy"))
                {
                    PublishId = tokens[0];
                    string MACSFile = @"\\OutputPath\\" + PublishId + ".txt";
                    string path =f.FullName;

                    string StoreFile = di.GetFiles().Where(file => file.Name.StartsWith(PublishId) && file.Name.Contains("SUBS")).Single().FullName;

                    using (FileStream fs = File.Open(StoreFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                    using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter(MACSFile))
                        {
                            String StoreNumber;
                            while ((StoreNumber = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(StoreNumber);
                                if (StoreNumber.Length > 5)
                                {
                                    using (FileStream fsProfile = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                                    using (BufferedStream bsProfile = new BufferedStream(fsProfile))
                                    using (StreamReader srProfile = new StreamReader(bsProfile))
                                    {
                                        outfile.WriteLine(srProfile.ReadToEnd().TrimEnd());
                                        
                                    }

                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: Any language can do this, what is the problem exactly? Read from one file, write to another.

Comment: @Evk : Problem is which language or OS would be able to handle this much big size. Output file can be around 150 GB.

Comment: Language and OS doesn't matter as long as you have free 150 GB on your drive. You will not build this file in memory - you will write it right away to the file.

Comment: @Evk: I thought the same but it's taking hours to generate output file of 150 GB. Added my C# code to question.

Comment: do you accept Command Line or PowerShell in Windows?

Comment: Did you check if your Hardware even supports your requirement (Copy 150 Gigs in 1 hour or less)? Have you considered reading from a different bus (not only different disc) than you are writing to? And 2.: Have you tried keeping the 20 MB you are copying over and over completely in memory?

Comment: I did realized that my Input and Output path was a shared drive. That was the biggest problem. When Trying in local path, I'm able to finish this in less than 5 mins. Thank you for help All.

Comment: Now, not sure if I should close my question, keep is as it is OR answer my own question. Any help?

Comment: It should be closed as the main problem is not in your code, and nor a situation for S.O., instead ServerFault. But is a bounty so Idk.

Answer (score 1):

You mention shell script. Here's a working shell example:

```
while read line; do
  echo "$line" >> Output
  cat File1 >> Output
done < File2
```

Here the lines of `File2` are being looped over and written along with the entirety of `File1` into an arbitrary output file `Output`.

Easily run by saving it in a local file `something.sh` and running `sh something.sh`.

Comment: Any chances that this would be able to generate 150 GB file within an hour?

Answer (score 1):

We could further optimise the code for performance, at the cost of memory. All refactor it to make it cleaner.

File1 : 6000 lines

File2 : 20Mb

As File 1, (smaller file) just contains a few number of lines, would read the entire file into memory and loop over it.

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(File1))
```

If you still have memory capacity, you can read the entire second file into memory as well

```
var file2 = File.ReadAllText(File2)
```

Now all you have to do is append everything to a 3rd file. Which we will not store in memory because of size.

So the entire code will be

```
var file2 = File.ReadAllText(File2);
var destinationFile = "destination/file/path";

foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(File1)){
File.AppendAllText(destinationFile, line);
File.AppendAllText(destinationFile, file2);
}
```

**Further Optimisation:** Skipped to keep code simple

File.AppendAllText is called twice, because we don't want to do line + file2 in code. It will allocate more memory.

To optimise this further you can use StringBuilder, load file2 into it.

```
var file2 = new StringBuilder(File.ReadAllText(File2));
```

And mutate it. This should, prevent the 2 calls to File.AppendAllText and give more performance.

Comment: Read this question is solved, in the comments.Local script runes in less than 5 min, Leaving my answer for further optimising it.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to reduce I/O time. You can try the case with a reading/writing in large portions (I think It is more efficient because I/O operations require to allocate/release resources of OS). So if you read all, aggregate the result in-memory, write to file, then it will spend less time on I/O. A higher speed here is reached by in-memory operations, because RAM and processor operations are very rapid to process in comparison with an IO operation.

1. File 1 - is small - read it once and keep the results in memory.
2. File 2 - is large - read it in chunks. For example, you can use streamReader.ReadLine() N times
3. Combine in-memory data of the first file with each chunk of the second one parallelly if possible.
4. Output - open/close stream only once, write after each chuck is processed.

*PS: no need in buffered streams here because file streams are already buffered.   Buffered streams are useful for network IO operations.*